# SingTask launchMode Doubts

Tags: android

I now have an Activity A Activity B and an A in manifest now I configure the android: launchMode for singleTask

Now add a button to jump in A to B , and then press the home button

After pressing the home Activity B will enter onpause onstop then click on the program icon will actually destroy B enters A This is why?

I did not go jump from B to A. Why B will be destroyed out of it ?

There is also a scene

There are now three Activity A B C

B in the configuration file to the startup mode is set to SingTask

A default entry Activity A - B - C in C when you press the home screen , and then click on the application at this time does not destroy the life cycle of a normal C enter onRestart onStart onResume This is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You created first activity as singleTask. *The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it*. Then second activity is created.

But when you press home then second will be destroyed because activity A is singleTask and activity B with in separate task which will not refer to A.

But when you create A, B, C and B has singleTask. Then A launched in Default mode and it referes to B which is singleTask, also C is in same task as of A. So it follows normal life-cycle.

You can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).